# Matlab: How to update the limit of a for loop dynamically?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, limit, updates

I'm working on the following code in matlab:

```
m=unique(x);
for i=1:length(m)
%some code that increase the number of unique values in x
.......
.......
%here I tried to update m 
m=unique(x);
end
```

Although  I have updated `m` by writing this line `m=unique(x);` before the for end, The limit of the for loop  still has the same old value. I need to update the limit of a for loop dynamically. Is that possible? if it is possible, how to do so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When MATLAB meets `for i = 1:length(m)`, it converts the statement into `for i = [1 2 3 ... length(m)]`. You can regard it as hard-coded. Thus, update for-limit inside a for loop does not have an effect.

```
m = unique(x);
i = 1;
while true
    if i > length(m)
        break
    end
    % do something
    i = i + 1;
    m = unique(x);
end
```

Comment: Or, a little bit simpler: `m = unique(x); ii = 0; while ii<numel(m), ii = ii + 1; doSomething; m = unique(x); end`

Comment: @LuisMendo Your answer is much better imo, too bad that it is just a comment.